# How do I give access to a user to administer only specific Entities on the Sonata Admin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

How do I give access to a user to administer only specific Entities on the Sonata Admin?

For instance, I have 3 entities, Schedules, Groups and Events which have their corresponding Sonata Admin configured. I want an user named sonata.editor who has access to only these Groups Entities admin and not others.

Comment: create a user and assign only needed roles

Answer (score 0):

Do you use ACL ? https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html

I'm not sure but it could be a solution